# MySQL returns syntax error on a server but not on another

Tags: sql, database, mariadb

I've been running this query for years, And now it throws a syntax error.
I know the query seems easy to fix but I'd like to know what option in configuration is responsable for this syntax error to be thrown.

Query:

`SELECT first_table.*,.second_table.one_column FROM first_table NATURAL JOIN second_table`

If I remove the `"."` from `".second_table.one_column"` it'd work just fine, But I need to know the reason why it works on other servers but not on this one.

**Edit:**

Both servers use the following sql mode :

> ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,​NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,​NO_ZERO_DATE,​ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,​NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

Comment: What does `SELECT @@version;` return on the database instance where this works?

Comment: It works on 10.4.28-MariaDB
Doesn't work on 8.0.36
But it used to work on lower versions.

Comment: that would only work if the dataabase name would be automatic attached, which should work at all, as a databaseobject is missing

Comment: Any more details about "automatic database name attaching" ? And how come that it's already attached in other servers ? Thanks.

Comment: well, it does work for [tag:mariadb] ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YrIdMiK2)). but it doesn't work for [tag:mysql], see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tMJFxmpH). are we really dealing with the same database? people tend to use [tag:mariadb] and [tag:mysql] interchangeably but they arguably different. but it seems the problem in this question to be a little known quirks which surprised me - i never wrote query that way before.

Comment: You're right, I haven't done the installation myself I assumed they were both the same, you're answer solves the mystery.

Comment: @BagusTesa 
The query itself might be unacceptable, but knowing the reason why it wouldn't work in different environments would be a lifesaver from other issues.

Comment: @MohammedCherkaoui guess Bill's suggestion to `SELECT @@version;` is a must before we assume the dbms.

Comment: How can they accept that completely invalid syntax? Must be a bug.

Comment: @jarlh Possible, I didn't mean to use that syntax it was a coincidence but I wanted to know what made it acceptable on a different server.

Comment: @BagusTesa After testing on MySQL 5.5 this syntax works until version 8.0

Comment: indeed, it seems to work on mysql 5.7 or earlier https://dbfiddle.uk/I6Qga7Ba or any version of mariadb (tested 11.4 and some earlier versions) but not mysql 8

Answer (score -1):

As mentionned by @Bagus Tesa, It works on MariaDB but not on MySQL.

Edit:
It works on previous versions of MySQL

Comment: File a bug report with MariaDB -- That looks like a syntax error to me.

Comment: @RickJames You think so ? Because I thought it assumed the database name as the currently used one, But it makes nosense though. I only faced this case because I had to do a batch modifications on files which left the dot before the table name.

Comment: That sounds like invalid syntax that MySQL catches but MariaDB does not catch.

Comment: @RickJames Well, MySQL used not to catch it too in versions prior to 8.0